# SQL Authentication with Textbox and AD Authentication

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Hi I am running two forms of Authentication.  The first authentication I run is a an AD Authentication which works fine.  The Second is to confirm that the username is in a SQL Database.  I am using this code to verify the username exists in SQL.

I get the error

Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader'

with this code....

```
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Username from dbo.users", con);

        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader sqlresult = cmd.ExecuteReader();


        if (txtLoginID.Text == sqlresult)
        {
            Response.Redirect("account/orders.aspx");// Authenticated user redirects to default.aspx
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("default.aspx");// Authenticated user redirects to default.aspx
        }
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: you are using SQLDataReader incorrectly. check the [Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems here.  First off your query:

```
select Username from dbo.users
```

Is pulling every record in the table.  This is not the correct way to check if the user name exists.  You need something like this:

```
select Username from dbo.users WHERE UserName = @UserName
```

Where `@UserName` is a [parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx) that contains the value from `txtLoginID.Text`.  Once you have done this you can use:

```
    if(sqlresult.HasRows)
    {
        Response.Redirect("account/orders.aspx");// Authenticated user redirects to default.aspx
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("default.aspx");// Authenticated user redirects to default.aspx
    }
```

You should also look at `using` statements.

While it isn't doesn't really matter if you use the above solution, the reason you are getting the error is pretty self explanatory.  You are attempting to compare a string value to a SqlDataReader object.  This is not possible.